# Can a package.json script access a dependency in the package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, package.json, npm-scripts

Let's say we have a main-module with 2 dependencies A and B.

- dependencyA has an executable script which we want to run as a package.json script in the main module. (yarn run:dependencyA)
- dependencyB needs to be dynamically imported by dependencyA.
- B can't be a direct dependency of A at build time.

```json
{
  "name": "main-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "run:dependencyA": "dependencyA",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dependencyA": "1.0.0",
    "dependencyB": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

How can the dependencyA script access dependencyB from the main-module when executed?

Comment: Is A a _peer_ dependency of B, then? NPM supports that too: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies.

Comment: Humm I think no, B does not need A as a dependency, only A needs B. This is if B is present in the main-module.
B is a 'plugin' that exports it's own definition, which A needs to import so it can register B in main-module.